# Inno Setup can't handle Source path with space

Tags: inno-setup

my application has this directory that I need to include in the install package:

```
bin\Win Files\*
```

So, in the `[Files]` section, I have this line:

```
Source: "bin\Win Files\*";     DestDir: "{app}\bin\Win Files"; Flags: ignoreversion; Permissions: everyone-modify
```

But at compile time, it keeps saying it can't find that directory due to space in the path, the exact error message is:

```
No files found matching "C:\dev\packages\MyApp\bin\Win Files\*"
```

I've tried the following, all failed:

```
Source: """bin\Win Files\*"""
Source: "\"bin\Win Files\*\""
Source: '"bin\Win Files\*"'
```

That directory has to be named like that, so what should I do?

Comment: I do not think your are right. Your script works for me without any problem. Inno Setup has no problem with spaces in the path. -- Does your script compile if you rename `Win Files` to `WinFiles`?

Comment: Yes, if I remove the space it will compile, but not with the space. I am using Inno Setup version 6.0.2, it fails when encounter that space in the source path, are you using a more recent version of inno setup?

Comment: I'm using 6.0.3, but it worked always + How exactly do you compile the script? Show us some screenshots and exact error message. + Can do `dir "bin\Win Files"` in Windows `cmd`? + Double check if it is a plain space (it might be a different whitespace).

Comment: Inside Inno Setup, there is the button compile (Ctrl+F9), not sure how to paste in here a screen capture... it is a plain white space, I am sure of it, and I am sure it is failing there in the inno setup program during compilation.

Comment: I just downloaded and installed the latest 6.0.3 version of inno setup program, and it failed as before. The exact error message is: `No files found matching "C:\dev\packages\MyApp\bin\Win Files\*"`

Comment: Proof that it works: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSmZC.png + Again, what do you get if you do `dir "C:\dev\packages\MyApp\bin\Win Files\*"` in Windows `cmd`?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I have more subdirectories under "Win Files" directory, I see you have just plain files under there, so perhaps, this means the Source directive can only handle first level directory and it can't include nested directories

Comment: Subfolders are not scanned by default. That has nothing to do with a space or not.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl ok, I would like to accept your explanation as the anwser if you can posted it as an answer.

Comment: I do not have an answer to your question. Maybe if you edit your question to ask what is really your problem (as I understand that the space is not the problem actually).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this:

```
[Files]
; Main application
Source: "{#SourceDir}\*"; DestDir: "{app}\"; Flags: recursesubdirs ignoreversion;
```

to copy all my files in one go to the installer. Note the `recursesubdirs` flag. I think spaces in the path (referenced here in the variable named `SourceDir`) are not actually a problem here.

Comment: I like this answer as this is what I was trying to do, that is to include all files in one go. I hope my own answer would help somebody to understand the Inno Setup file logic a bit better.

Comment: Actually, there is a problem with this, the new version of Inno Setup 6.0.3 can't handle a chain of folder only directories. For example: c:\src\d1\d2\d3, only subdirectory without any standalone files!!!

Comment: I guess the `[Files]` section is meant to copy files. Not empty directories. Check out `[Dirs]`. (http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=dirssection)

Comment: Yes, if there is at least 1 files in a directory, then the Source line can include that directory, the * is meant to be convenient to include all in on shot. I see from the link that the [Dirs] directive is for creating empty folders, so it is still a bit of inconvenience if one has to create the chain of empty folders explicitly instead of creating them in one shot...

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the misunderstanding about the directory/file structure scanning mechanism in Inno Setup.

First of all, as @Martin Prikryl pointed out, one can include path that has space in it.

I think the following two rules are the key to this issue:

1. One cannot specify a folder that has no standalone files (e.g. empty folder or a folder that only has sub-directories). In my case: I have the following file structure per this question:

   ```
   bin\Win Files\Libs\
   bin\Win Files\Plugins\
   ```

So `Source: "bin\Win Files\*";` will fail. If there is at least one standalone file under the `"bin\Win Files\"` folder, then the source line will work.

2. Inno Setup requires each folder be explicitly specified in the `[Files]` section as below:

   ```
   Source: "bin\Win Files\Libs\*"; DestDir: "{app}\bin\Win Files\Libs"; 
       Flags: ignoreversion; Permissions: everyone-modify

   Source: "bin\Win Files\Plugins\*"; DestDir: "{app}\bin\Win Files\Plugins"; 
       Flags: ignoreversion; Permissions: everyone-modify
   ```

as `Source: "bin\Win Files\*";` will NOT include the sub-directories automatically, it is only used to include the standalone files under the `bin\Win Files\` folder.